# Google Calendar Quick Add Event with Description

Tags: ios, google-calendar-api

I’m integrating google calendar in my app.
I’ve a custom class to authenticate and add events to the calendar. Simple events are added successfully. Now I want to add events with description and having problems.
My function to add events is working fine but I don’t know how to mention this extra parameter for “description”.
Here’s my function which is working perfectly

```
self.googleOAuth.callAPI(apiURLString , withHttpMethod: httpMethod_POST, postParameterNames: ["calendarId","text"], postParameterValues: [self.calendarID, stringToPost])
```

I’ll have to add an extra parameter which is “fields” and in “fields" there is a “description” field. Reference [Google Calendar Quick Add](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/quickAdd#examples)

I’m struggling how to add this extra parameter in the `postParameterNames:` and `postParameterValues:`

Any suggestions or solution to this?

Comment: I'm not an iOS expert, but the field parameter from the quickAdd method is intended to specify which "fields" you would like to include in the response and not to generate a description. As far as your question goes, try taking a look at this code sample from Google GitHub: https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client/blob/master/Examples/CalendarSample/CalendarSampleWindowController.m Hope this helps! :)

Comment: You're absolutely right about the "fields" parameter. I already tried the code from GitHub but it has issues so not using that. I have a custom class to connect to google calendar service. What I've figured out that I have to use "Insert" instead of "quickAdd".

Comment: Glad it worked out, cheers! :)